# FactoryBot not trigger callback in trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, minitest

I have a factory that has a trait. I've added a callback for after create but the callback is not being triggered. I know this because I can't pry in. I'm using FactoryBot 5 and Rails 4.2.11

```
factory :document do
  trait :signed do
    after :create do |doc|
      binding.pry
      doc.signatures << create(:signatures)
    end
  end
end
```

**my test**

```
  let!(:document) { build(:document, :signed) }

  %w[...].each do |field|
    it "filters by document.#{field}" do
      ...
      co.contents << create(:content, documents: [document])
      ... 
   end
  end
```

Also tried using transient instead of trait and it does not work fire

```
transient do
  signed { false }
end

after :create do |doc, options|
  binding.pry
  doc.signatures << create(:signature) if options.signed
end


let!(:document) { build(:document, signed: true) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `after(:create)` callback isn't invoked as you are are not *creating* a `document` with `FactoryBot.create`.

The following code should work.

```
let!(:document) { create(:document, :signed) }
```

For more info, read the [FactoryBot callback docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks).